# PHP Curl for encrypted pages

Tags: php, curl, encryption, web-crawler

I do a php curl to this website
http://www.hoovers.com/company-information/company-search.html

But it returned 404. Looks like something encrypted or what.

Can you give some clue about this problem.
Thanks

```
        // Get cURL resource
    $curl = curl_init();
    // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.hoovers.com/company-information/company-search.html',
    ));
    // Send the request & save response to $resp
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    // Close request to clear up some resources
    curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: do you mind sharing the code you are using ?

Comment: I'm using codeigniter
It doesnt even work for native curl php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like their web server is rejecting requests based on HTTP headers. Or it might be on the application level as well. Try this

```
<?php
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER=>1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.hoovers.com/company-information/company-search.html',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> array(
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0', 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5'
        )
    ));

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

//debug
print_r($resp);
?>
```